# Get individual value from radio button on array use JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

now im doing some PHP project combine with JQuery for radio button. Im new for JQuery code. now i making array for radio button. i want to get individual value when i click one of the radio button.

here is the code that i trying. before that. i make a sample on this link https://repl.it/@ferdinandgush/get-value-radio-button.  just press RUN button on the top then you able to test it.

html

```
<table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Item</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Price</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Deal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 10 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"> 
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pencil</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 5 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="5"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 8 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="8"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">spidol</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 15 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="15"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
      $('.radioDeal').on('input', function(){

        console.log($(this).attr("name"));

        var name = $(this).attr("name");

        console.log($('input[name="+ name +"]:checked').val());
    
    });
 });
```

so what im focusing is, i able to get individual attribute name when i click on of the radio button. from that attribute name, i want to get the value. but not work.

do i able to do that?.

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it, you can get the value like this:

```
var checkedvalue =  $('input[name="'+ name +'"]:checked').val();
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(function() {
      $('.radioDeal').on('input', function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var checkedvalue =  $('input[name="'+ name +'"]:checked').val();
        console.log(name+' = '+checkedvalue);   
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Item</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Price</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Deal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 10 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"> 
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pencil</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 5 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="5"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 8 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="8"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">spidol</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 15 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="15"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `change` event triggers when state changes from **not checked** to **checked** it is therefore the ideal event to use as the `this` refers to the `radio` just checked:

```
$('.radioDeal').on('change', function() {
    console.log( `${this.name} = ${this.value}` );
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.radioDeal').on('change', function() {
        console.log( `${this.name} = ${this.value}` );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Item</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Price</th>
        <th class="tg-qh0q">Deal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 10 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax"> 
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][0]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pencil</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 5 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="5"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][1]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 8 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="8"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][3]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="tg-0lax">spidol</td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">$ 15 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="15"></td>
        <td class="tg-0lax">
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="yes">yes
            <input class="radioDeal" type="radio" name="deal[12][4]" value="no" >No
        </td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```